# Read a file line by line and replace certain words

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with certain words in every line. Example:

> word1 more words
>
> word15 even more words

What I want to do is to replace the first word with a certain word. For example; if the first word is "word1" it will be replaced with "yes" and if the first word in the line is "word15" it will be replaced with "no".

So I need a loop to go through every line and check the first word and replace it with a certain word.

This is what I have so far and it doesn't do anything remotely close to what I want to do:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (ukazi.txt) do (
set var=%%a
set new=%var:ls=dir%
set new=$
echo %new%
)
pause
```

I'm new to batch and I'm getting confused more and more every minute. I'll appreciate the help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this :

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (c:\temp\word.txt) do call :REPLACE "%%i"

:REPLACE
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in (%1) do (
    set test=%%i
    set test=!test:word15=no!
    set test=!test:word1=yes!
    echo  !test! %%j
)
```

the keys are :

- to use `EnableDelayedExpansion` so that the variables will be expanded at the execution time rather than at the end of script (when you use this, the variables will be reference using !variable_name!
- use the 'in-place' variable replacement (ie : `%variable_name:X=Y%` will replace every X character by Y in the variable content )
- `%1` is the value of the first argument passed to the subroutine

Comment: It works! Thank you! But there are some thigns that I would like to understand. What's %1 there for in the second FOR?

Comment: Thank you :) Oh and just one more thing. Why is there "tokens=1,*" in the second for? Wouldn't it be the same if it was just "tokens="*"?

Comment: this is because you want to replace only the first world of the line (maybe this world can appears somewhere else where you dont want it to be replaced) ;). Please consider marking this as an answer if it had helped you

Comment: There are at least two problems with this approach. The first is that the substitution must be executed in the order `word15` then `word1` since `word1` is a substring of `word15`. Any word which is a substring of a previous replaced word must be processed later. Any word which is a substring of a replacement word must be replaced earlier. Also, the replacement occurs wherever the replaced string occurs - so `another` would be replaced by "a `the replacement for not` her" if `not` is in the replace-me list.

Comment: @Magoo your response is certainly more robust but this is not easy to read... choosing your solution may be a better option depending of the  number and complexity of the replacements. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
:: set up substitution elements from replacements.txt
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (replacements.txt) DO SET "$%%a"
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a IN (q21450455.txt) DO CALL :rep1 %%a "%%b"
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:rep1
IF defined $%1 (CALL SET "newword=%%$%1%%") ELSE (SET newword=%1)
ECHO %newword% %~2
GOTO :eof
```

No that easy to follow - so I'll explain.

First, the `set $` command is executed, which will "list" any variables that start `$`, one to a line in the format `$alreadyset=previousvalue`. The `2^>nul` ensures an error message (`Environment variable $ not found`) is not shown. The caret (`^`) tells `cmd` that the redirector `>` is part of the line to be executed, not the `FOR`.

So, for each line of output (if any), `for /f` tokenises the line such that each [series of] `=` characters (the character [set]**bewteen** the `delims=` and the `"`) is a 'token separator'. Token 1 is applied to the metavariable (`%%a` in this case). It's possible to nominate a sequence of tokens, which then get applied to the succeeding metavariables.

so, `$alreadyset=previousvalue` is tokenised to `$alreadyset` and `previousvalue` and `$alreadyset` assigned to `%%a`; the `set` command sets `%%a` to an empty string, so `$alreadyset` is set to an empty string and hence deleted from the environment.

The `set "var=value"` syntax is used to ensure that any trailing spaces on the line are **not** included in the value assigned. Spaces are a little hard to see...

The next `FOR /F` uses no delimiters (no characters between `=` and `"`) which overrides the default delimiter set like <kbd>Space</kbd>. The entire line is now assigned to `%%a`. so if `replacements.txt` contains

```
word1=yes
word15=no
```

then the `set` is executed as `set "$word1=yes"` (and so on for the rest of the file)

Finally, there's really just one `for` loop and a subroutine. The `(for...)>filename` construct sends anything `ECHO`ed during the loop into a file - even if it's `echo`ed in a subroutine. `>file` means make a new file, `>>file` would mean `append to an existing file if there is one or make a new one.`

This final `for/f` reads ech line from my test file, `q21450455.txt`

```
word1 more words
not here word1
not at all here
word15 even more words
```

tokenising using the default separators, assigning the first token (1) to `%%a` and the remainder (*) to `%%b`. Then the subroutine `rep1` is `call`ed and two parameters are passed - `%%a` as the first (the first word from the line, up to the first separator) and `"%%b"` as the second. The entire rest-of-line is in `%%b` - but that may contain separators, so `"quoting it"` keeps the entire rest-of-line together as one element.

In `:rep1`, we see whether the variable `$%1` is defined. %1 is the first parameter to the routine, hence the first word from the file, so the statement will see whether `$word1` exists as an environment variable. If it does, we set `newword` to the contents of `$%1` hence we need to **call** set ...= %% $%1 %%. This is a parsing trick and executes set ...=%v$word1%, or whatever the first word is - and that was set into the environment earlier.

If `$word1` is not defined in the environment, then `newword` is simply set to the first parameter (ie. the first word from the line of the file).

Finally, we `echo` the newword and `%~2` which means `the second parameter, with any enclosing quotes removed` - and this is redirected to the file.

Job done.

Comment: I don't really need something as complex as this since I'm a complete beginner but thanks a lot! I definately learned a lot of new things when reading this :)