# BATCH Dir command and replace some variables

Tags: file, batch-file, dir

First question:

I can list path names & folder names, but I have a problem.

I don't need path names, look "<-- this":

```
C:\Users\Ad\Desktop\ready_pc\data\daiva\a\building <-- this.
C:\Users\Ad\Desktop\ready_pc\data\daiva\a\building\daiva.dds
```

My batch command:

```
dir /b /s > fileslist.txt
```

Another question:

I need to change imported file path names:

Imported:

```
C:\Users\Ad\Desktop\ready_pc\data\daiva\a\building\daiva.dds
```

Must be:

```
d:\another_work\ready_pc\data\daiva\a\building\daiva.dds
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "change imported file path names"? Move the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another parameter `/a-d`. This means "Attribute: NoDir":

```
dir /b /s /a-d
```

EDIT (replacing string adapted to your needs):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (fileslist.txt) do (
 set line=%%i
 set line=!line:C:\Users\Ad\Desktop\=d:\another_work\!
 echo !line! >>newfile.txt
)
```

Comment: Hey thank you this works well, can you answer second question?

Comment: I just need replace some directories. Like this:

C:\Users\Alihan\Desktop\ready_pc\data\
to
d:\works\released\

Comment: Take a look to `move /?` to rename a directory. Does this help?

Comment: No, I need to make this job in imported list of files txt file

Comment: Then this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450455/read-a-file-line-by-line-and-replace-certain-words

Comment: In answer, only echo the results

echo  !test! %%j

I need import echos to a txt file?

Comment: He just write last token of file list? so 1 line. replace worked but no for echo

Comment: sorry, it was a single `>` where there should have been two (`>>`) in the last line (`echo !line! >> newfile.txt`)